# Dropdown lists are not working - how to remove one option to another with loop?

Tags: javascript, html

We have a homework and it goes like this. We have to create five dropdown lists. The first dropdown list must be inserted 1 - 5 numbers and user will choose one number among the five. The second one is still the same but without the chosen number of the user. The third one must have no first and second chosen numbers. Until so forth. There's a thrill in this activity though. Once I changed my first dropdown list, the following lists must be back to prime process.

I've made some changes though but it doesn't change at all. I tried to change the values of my loops but it won't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Option</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function abela(){
            //var first = document.getElementById("one").innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("one").innerHTML = "";
            for (var ado = 1; ado<=5; ado++){
                document.getElementById("one").innerHTML += "<option>" + ado +  "</option>";
            }
        }
        function adonis(){
            document.getElementById("two").innerHTML = "";
            var hey = document.getElementById("one").value;
            for (var nis = 1; nis<=5; nis++){
                if (nis == hey) {
                    continue;
                }
                document.getElementById("two").innerHTML += "<option>" + nis +  "</option>";
            }

            document.getElementById("three").innerHTML = "";
            var hey = document.getElementById("one").value;
            var yow = document.getElementById("two").value;


            for (var jus = 1; jus<=5; jus++){
                if (jus == hey || jus == yow) {
                    continue;
                }
                document.getElementById("three").innerHTML += "<option>" + jus +  "</option>";
            }
            document.getElementById("four").innerHTML = "";
            var hey = document.getElementById("one").value;
            var yow = document.getElementById("two").value;
            var lit = document.getElementById("three").value;

            for (var top = 1; top<=5; top++){
                if (top == hey || top == yow || top == lit) {
                    continue;
                }
                document.getElementById("four").innerHTML += "<option>" + top +  "</option>";
            }
            document.getElementById("five").innerHTML = "";
            var hey = document.getElementById("one").value;
            var yow = document.getElementById("two").value;
            var lit = document.getElementById("three").value;
            var pol = document.getElementById("four").value;

            for (var lop = 1; lop<=5; lop++){
                if (lop == hey || lop == yow || lop == lit || lop == pol) {
                    continue;
                }
                document.getElementById("five").innerHTML += "<option>" + lop +  "</option>";
            }

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="abela();">
    <select id = "one" onchange="adonis();"></select><br>
    <select id = "two" onchange="adonis();"></select><br>
    <select id = "three" onchange="adonis();"></select><br>
    <select id = "four" onchange="adonis();"></select><br>
    <select id = "five" onchange="adonis();"></select>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect the output would be like this: First dropdown list: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 "I'll choose a number. I chose number 4". Second dropdown list: 1, 2, 3, 5 "I'll choose a number. I chose number 5". Third dropdown list: 1, 2, 3 "I'll choose a number. I chose number 3". Fourth dropdown list: 1, 2 "I'll choose a number. I chose number 1". Fifth dropdown list: 2

Comment: And what's your question? Have you tried to debug anything?

Comment: How to properly code this thing? How to click something on a drop down list and change values from one another?

Comment: Your adonis function should:
1. Get the position of the element that fired it
2. Get the selected values from the current and the previous selects (if there are any)
3. Clear the next elements innerHTML and populate it with the remaining values (exluding the values from step 2)
4. Disable the rest of the select elements

You can add this function as an eventListener to all of your select elements and you should be ok

Comment: I don't get it. What code that I didn't include?

Answer (score 2):

As you have 5 `select` boxes, logically only 4 of them should respond to a `change` event (the last one doesn't affect any other one if changed or not).

So, how would we get to your desired outcome, keeping consideration if a `select` is changed again the next ones must be cleared (so you can choose again with the same functionality you wanted to have) :

- select all the `select` boxes and put them in array. No need for their `ID`s as all of them (excluding the fifth one) will have the same functionality (the same event handler).
- an `array` containing the values (from 1 to 5) to be shown as the `select` boxes `option`s, so we can populate the next `select` based on that `array` excluding the selected value from the current `select` box.
- another `array` to keep track on the selected values from all the `select` boxes, so based on that we will know which values to exclude when working with the last `array` (above one that has values from 1 to 5).
- also we should consider the possibility if a `select` box that has been already choosed a value from (already been selected an option) is again changed so all the next `select` boxes must be cleared and only the next one to be filled with the appropriate values (to have the same functionality even if a `select` is re-changed in the middle of the process).

The next example illustrates what's being said and has the functionality you want, it has a wealth of helpful comments to assist you when reading :

```js
/** 
* ## constants and variables used ##
* selectBoxes: the "select" boxes found in the page.
* values: an array containing the value from 1 to 5 that will be used to populate the "select" boxes dynamically.
* clearBox(elArr, idx): a helper function to clear all the "select" boxes elements passed in the parameter "elArr", the other parameter "idx" is used to nullify the values selected from the "select" boxes (look at the "selectedOptions" variable description) starting from the index "idx".
* filterCallback(v): used as a callback for the built-in "filter" method. Used to distinguish if a value is still usable (not already selected) in order to populate the "select" boxes.
* createElement(tagName, attributes): create an HTML element "tagName" and assign the "attributes" to it.
* selectedOptions: an array to keep track on the selected values of the "select" boxes.
**/
const selectBoxes = [...document.querySelectorAll('select')],
  values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  clearBox = (elArr, idx) => {
    let l = 0;
    /** nullify the "selectedOptions" array from the index "idx" **/
    for (let i = idx; i < selectedOptions.length; i++) selectedOptions[i] = null;
    /** loop through the "select" boxes to be cleared **/
    elArr.forEach(el => {
      l = el.options.length;
      /** loop through the children of the "select" and remove them **/
      for (let i = l - 1; i >= 0; i--) el.remove(i);
    });
  },
  filterCallback = v => {
    const l = selectedOptions.length;
    /** check if the value "v" already has been choosed **/
    for (let i = l - 1; i >= 0; i--)
      if (selectedOptions[i] === v) return false;
    return true;
  },
  createElement = (tagName, attributes) => {
    const el = document.createElement(tagName);
    /** apply the attributes **/
    if(typeof attributes === 'object') for(let i in attributes) if(attributes.hasOwnProperty(i)) el[i] = attributes[i];
    return el;
  },
  selectedOptions = [null, null, null, null];

/** 
* loop through the "select" boxes and apply the "change" event handler.
* el: the current "select" in the set that is being operated.
* i: its index in the "selectBoxes" array
**/
selectBoxes.forEach((el, i) => {
  /** apply the "change" event **/
  el.addEventListener('change', e => {
    /** remember, the last "select" box is excluded and have no functionality it's only populated dynamically **/
    if (i !== selectBoxes.length - 1) {
      /** empty the next "select" **/
      clearBox(selectBoxes.slice(i + 1), i + 1);
      /** add the current selected option value to "selectedOptions" **/
      selectedOptions[i] = +el.options[el.selectedIndex].value; /** note the plus siign "+" in front is used to automatically convert the value into an integer **/
      /** cretae a disabled and selected "option" to act as an info text **/
      const disabledOption = createElement('option', {
        disabled: true,
        selected: true,
        textContent: 'choose option'
      });
      /** append that "option" to the next "select" box **/
      selectBoxes[i + 1].appendChild(disabledOption);
      /** filter the values "array" to get only the non-selected values and then populate the next "select" box **/
      values.filter(filterCallback).forEach(el => {
        const o = createElement('option', {
          value: el,
          textContent: el
        });
        /** add the "option" to the next "select" box **/
        selectBoxes[i + 1].append(o);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/** for demo purposes **/
select {
  display: block; /** every select sits on a new line **/
}
```

```html
<!-- nothing too fancy here just the first select has by default its options along with a disabled and selected option to appear as an information text "choose option" -->

<!-- whenever a "select" is changed the next one will be populated based on your requirements and it will have a selected and disabled option as the first one to act as a info text -->

<!-- no "id" attributes used as I already said all the "select" boxes (excluding the last one) will be treated the same way so no need to select them individually -->

<select>
  <option selected disabled>choose option</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<select></select>
<select></select>
<select></select>
<select></select>
```

**Some helpful links :**

> Learn more about [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) function.
>
> Learn more about [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) function.
>
> Learn more about [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function.
>
> Learn more about [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) function.